# I am unable to deploy phoenix app to heroku because of failed dependency (called coherence) compilation, how to make it work?

Tags: heroku, deployment, elixir, phoenix-framework

So to start I made an Elixir application using Phoenix framework.
This application uses coherence dependency for authentication to the website. This dependency was installed as it is advised on the git repo with `-full` argument to install all the options coherence has.

Then, I did just change a couple of lines in `config.exs` file of my project to use mailgun service for mailing and put credentials over there.

Next, I installed and configured my other deps (they have nothing to do with coherence).

Locally, my application could compile and run without problems.

Then, I wanted to deploy it to Heroku using Phoenix guidelines.
When I completed all the steps, I got an error when trying to push the application to Heroku.

I then tried to check the file `lib/mix/tasks/coherence.clean.ex` and the line 162 where I found a comment that said there is an error with updating a config file, but I couldn't figure out what that means and how to solve that.

I tried to make a fresh phoenix application, installing coherence with the same or different options and afterward deploying it following the Phoenix guidelines. Every time I was getting the same error.

I also want to note that I did try to create `elixir_buildpack.config` file and putting `always_rebuild=true` there and had no success. (it is a solution mentioned in troubleshooting section of deploying to Heroku guide)

So, my question is, what do I need to change in my `config.exs` file (or elsewhere) in order to make at least a fresh application with coherence installed to compile and work on Heroku?

useful links:
[coherence dep github link](https://github.com/smpallen99/coherence)

Thanks a ton guys.

Comment: Try adding `elixir_version=1.3.2` to `elixir_buildpack.config` and then deploying.

Comment: Thanks Dogbert, that solved my issue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Heroku Buildpack for Elixir](https://github.com/HashNuke/heroku-buildpack-elixir) currently defaults to Elixir 1.2.6 while the code that throws that error uses the `else` syntax with `with`, a feature [that was added in Elixir 1.3.0](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/commit/0a7e2ae2ca41da5ba27dfd05e5c0a90eaed01bdd), so you need to set the Elixir version to use to 1.3.0 or later by adding the following to `elixir_buildpack.config`:

```
elixir_version=1.3.2
```